# Mouse pointer swiping in Flexslider from WooThemes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, flexslider

I am working with the latest version of `Flexslider` from `Woo Themes` and `Bootstrap 3.3.5`.

I am wondering if there is functionality for swiping with the mouse pointer? It has left and right arrows and touch swipe, but I can't seem to find anything based on swiping with the mouse pointer from a PC/laptop.

This is all that I currently have so far:

```
<div class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
          <li style="background-color: aqua;">
               <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
          </li>
          <li style="background-color: yellow;">
               <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And my `JavaScript` code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "slide",
          pauseOnHover: true,
          slideshowSpeed: 3000,
          after: function () {
               $('.flexslider').resize();
          }
     });
});
```

I have looked through the docs but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that years ago, so not shure it will still work on most recent release of Flexslider; anyway maybe i will point you in the right direction...
Basically you should add a drag event to flexslider, so: 
1) first of all implement the [jquery.event.drag](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/) plug in
2)in jquery.flexslider.js add a block to support the new event, like this:

```
if (vars.drag) {
slider.bind('drag', function(event, delta) {
event.preventDefault();
var target = (delta.deltaX < 0) ? slider.getTarget('next') : slider.getTarget('prev');
slider.flexAnimate(target, vars.pauseOnAction);
});
}
```

you can easily find where to place it just finding where the other events support are, like this:

```
if (vars.mousewheel) {
...
}
if (vars.drag) {
...
}
```

3) Add the event to the defaults ones:

```
$.flexslider.defaults = {
...
drag: false,
...
}
```

4) Finally activate it when you call the Flexslider instance in your HTML page:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
animation: 'slide',
...
...
drag: true
});
```